# Drag and drop from Kendo Grid to kendo Treeview in mvc

Tags: kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, grid, treeview

I have a kendo grid and kendo treeview; the kendo grid data is bound to a database and the treeview is currently empty. How can I drag a single column single value from the grid to treeview? Could someone provide some suggestions or examples on how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **kendo draggable**, here is the overview :

> [LINK](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/draganddrop/overview)

To summary them up

1. make your grid as kendo draggable,
2. make your treeview droppable target,
3. on the drop function of the droppable target, do the logic to remove item from grid, then add it to treeview

HERE some raw example

> [kendo dojo (grid to treeview)](http://dojo.telerik.com/eWIgu/2)
>
> [kendo dojo (listview to treeview)](http://dojo.telerik.com/IvuFo)